# Java Desktop API, Launch .cmd file

Tags: java, windows, api, desktop-application

I want to use the Desktop API to lauch .cmd file on Windows.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(config.getCommandFilePath()));
```

But this launches the .cmd file as if it were called from the current directory. So it isn't the same as double-clicking the .cmd file.

Any ideas how to call the file as if we were in the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/95686/change-current-directory-to-the-batch-file-directory) answer, it can help.

Comment: okay that nearly worked. But having the /D at the back produces an error. Having it like that works fine on XP and 7 cd /d "%~dp0"